# how to convert nested dict to dataframe using python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I need to convert this dict to dataframe/csv

```
data= {
  "message": {
    "id": 474735,
    "token": "GI797jMv8FuG",
    "direction": "outgoing",
    "message_id": "t",
    "to": "user@email.com",
    "from": "user@email.com",
    "subject": "Test Message at July 05, 2022 16:10",
    "timestamp": 1657017652.063772,
    "spam_status": "NotChecked",
    "tag": null
  },
  "status": "Sent",
  "details": "Message for  accepted by aspmx.l.google.com (142.251.12.26) (from 49.248.200.108)",
  "output": "250 2.0.0 OK  1657017654 f1-20020a63de01000000b0040d4ea0274fsi11524255pgg.697 - gsmtp\n",
  "sent_with_ssl": false,
  "timestamp": 1657017654.6172404,
  "time": 1.26
}
```

I used this website
https://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm
and I'm getting the output as I want but  need the code to convert dict to dataframe so i can put this in my script
please file the output table in the attachment

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for sharing your question with us. It'd be best if you could provide what you have tried so far, as well as another row for your dataframe (since the data structure is somehow vague). In that case, I'm sure you'll reach the desired answer much faster. Sincerely

Comment: I tried  to convert dict to dataframe without modifying anything in dict variable but the structure of json not perfect format(nested dict)to get in the form of table and row but when i use single dict it is giving me output

Comment: this dict / JSON data is API output which I want to store in  CSV format, for this I'm using flask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `dictionary` with the default value of `list` and add each element in this `dictionary`.

```
import pandas as pd

tmp = {}
for k,v in data.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        for a,b in v.items():
            tmp.setdefault(f'{k}/{a}', []).append(b)
    else:
        tmp.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
        
        
        
pd.DataFrame(tmp)
```

Output:

```
   message/id   message/token   message/direction   message/message_id  message/to  message/from    message/subject message/timestamp   message/spam_status message/tag status  details output  sent_with_ssl   timestamp   time
0   474735      GI797jMv8FuG    outgoing                     t   user@email.com user@email.com  Test Message at July 05, 2022 16:10 1.657018e+09    NotChecked  null    Sent    Message for accepted by aspmx.l.google.com (1...    250 2.0.0 OK 1657017654 f1-20020a63de01000000...    false   1.657018e+09    1.26
```

Answer (score 3):

or you can use this build in function from `pandas`

```
pd.json_normalize(data)
```

output:

```
status  details output  sent_with_ssl   timestamp   time    message.id  message.token   message.direction   message.message_id  message.to  message.from    message.subject message.timestamp   message.spam_status message.tag
Sent    Message for  accepted by aspmx.l.google.com (142.251.12.26) (from 49.248.200.108)   "250 2.0.0 OK  1657017654 f1-20020a63de01000000b0040d4ea0274fsi11524255pgg.697 - gsmtp "    False   1657017654.6172404  1.26    474735  GI797jMv8FuG    outgoing    t   user@email.com  user@email.com  Test Message at July 05, 2022 16:10 1657017652.063772   NotChecked
```